# Materialized Views force and complete

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

What is the difference between force and complete refreshes in Materialized Views

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1 REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND AS SELECT * FROM T1;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1 REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND AS SELECT * FROM T1;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1 REFRESH ON DEMAND AS SELECT * FROM T1;
```

Need Just a brief difference between these statements?

Answer (score 6):

### COMPLETE

Refreshes by recalculating the materialized view's defining query.

### FAST

Applies incremental changes to refresh the materialized view using the information logged in the materialized view logs, or from a SQL*Loader direct-path or a partition maintenance operation.

### FORCE

Applies FAST refresh if possible; otherwise, it applies COMPLETE refresh.

### NEVER

Indicates that the materialized view will not be refreshed with refresh mechanisms.

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm) are the best available reference!!